# Upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 failed, now neither Software Center nor Software Updater will open

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, apt, updates, software-center

The update to 13.04 was offered, I accepted but it failed. Now neither Software Centre nor Updater will open. SC opens for a second then closes; Updater tells me:

**Failed to load the package list
This is a serious problem. Try again later. If this problem appears again, please report an error to the developers.
E:The package defoma needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.**

This isn't the first time I have had problems with software sources on 12.10. Both my desktop and laptop stopped getting updates and I resolved the issue by following solutions online involving cleaning and updating the package lists. I have followed various solutions this time but without success.

I am currently downloading the ISO for 13.04. Can I update with this or can it only be used for a clean install? I would rather upgrade and keep my apps.

HELP!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can upgrade with the ISO, you have both options upgrade (keeping your apps) or clean install. But you need to be connected to the web to be able to upgrade, use an ethernet cable instead of wifi if you can.

Comment: Tried upgrading from the CD, I have the problem where it hangs forever at "saving user apps" or whatever. So I'm stuck between two known Ubuntu bugs that nobody seems to have a fix for.

Really disappointed with this build of Ubuntu, it has more bugs than a flea circus. Can't believe that the bugs are even preventing me from escaping to a newer version!